# Should I split a post I made on the main site?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I made [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236846/gdb-run-command-fails-with-cannot-insert-breakpoint-1-debugging-a-rust-fu) on the main site which contains 2 problems related to each other. Should I split it into 2 posts (specifically, one about the GDB issue and another about the buggy Rust program), and if so, how should I do that?

Comment: @RobertLongson To be clear, I meant should I make 2 posts about the 2 different parts of the original post (specifically, one about the GDB issue and another about the buggy Rust program), or is it OK if I keep them as the single post? I edited my post to hopefully make this clearer.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, I've taken your advice,  so I guess this issue is resolved. With that in mind, should I just leave this post as is, or do I delete it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd certainly start with "I can't put breakpoints on this Rust 'Hello, World!' program". Of course to do that I'd need to find or write a really simple "Hello, World!" program and put that in the question.

Then I'd use that knowledge to debug the Rust problem I actually had, and only if that failed would I ask a second question.